# Variadic Templates and RValue refs

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, lvalue, rvalue

Consider the following C++ code

```
template <class... Args>
void f (const int x, const int y, Args&&... args) {
  // Do something
}
```

As far as I understand,`Args` here could either be lvalue or rvalue references, depending on the type deduction at compile time.

So, I should be able to call the function using -

```
float x = 40.0;
f<int, float, double>(10, 20, 30, x, 50.0);
```

This gives me an error saying that it could not cast x from type `float` to type `float&&`.

How do I define a function with a variadic template that accepts both lvalue and rvalue references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As far as I understand, `Args` here could either be lvalue or rvalue references, depending on the type deduction at compile time.

You're half right. `Args&&` would be either an lvalue or rvalue reference. But `Args` itself is either an lvalue reference or *not a reference*. A simpler case:

```
template <typename T> void foo(T&& ) { }

foo(1); // T is int
int x;
foo(x); // T is int&
```

When you specify `float` for `x`, you are specifying that that particular argument will have type `float&&`, and you cannot implicitly convert an lvalue `float` to an rvalue. You would have to cast it (via `std::move`):

```
f<int, float, double>(10, 20, 30, std::move(x), 50.0);
```

Or specify that it's an lvalue via `float&`:

```
f<int, float&, double>(10, 20, 30, x, 50.0);
```

Or simply let deduction do its thing:

```
f(10, 20, 30, x, 50.0);
```

Comment: The simple deduction gives an error saying... `.....file.h:41:87: note:   cannot convert ‘x’ (type ‘float’) to type ‘float&&’`. I fixed the typo with the template...

Comment: @subzero Not with exactly the function in your question, it won't.

Answer (score 4):

If you specify argument, you have to give lvalue reference:

```
f<int, float&, double>(10, 20, 30, x, 50.0);
```

or simply let compiler deduce for you

```
f(10, 20, 30, x, 50.0);
```